# Autoload classes using namespace within Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, namespaces, symfony-1.4, autoload

I want to include the phpleague's oauth client (https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client) on my symfony (1.4) project, but it's using namespace everywhere, so I looked on a workaround and came up with using Symfony2 Universal autoloader, together with this piece of code in my projectConfiguration.class.php

```
 public function namespacesClassLoader() 
 {
   $loader = new UniversalClassLoader();
   $loader->registerNamespaces(array(
        'League' => __DIR__ . '/../lib/League',
    ));
   $loader->register();
 }
```

That function being called inside the setup(). This doesn't work when I try to instantiate a provider like this

```
$provider = new League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google(array(
            'clientId' => '',
            'clientSecret' => '',
            'redirectUri' => $redirect_url
        ));
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was fixed long time ago, but for anyone interested I just needed to change this

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'League' => __DIR__ . '/../lib/League',
));
```

to this

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'League' => __DIR__ . '/../lib',
));
```