# I can't use Autoloader from Symfony2 in Symfony 1.4 for load this namespaced classes

Tags: namespaces, classloader, symfony-1.4, autoload

I want to use this php library with namespaced classes in my Symfony 1.4 project: https://github.com/donquixote/cellbrush.

I'm not quite familiar with the namespaces concept. So when i fisrt try the to use the main class of this library, according to its docs, i just did:

```
$table = \Donquixote\Cellbrush\Table\Table::create();
```

And i got this fatal error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Donquixote\Cellbrush\Table\Table' not found in D:\SF_ROOT_DIR\apps\frontend\modules\home\actions\actions.class.php

So i searched for a solution, and supposedly there is one: [stackoverflow sol 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254113/loading-namespaced-classes-with-symfony-1-4s-autoloader), [stackoverflow sol 1 eg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22068377/autoload-classes-using-namespace-within-symfony-1-4?answertab=votes#tab-top), but when i try to implement it i still get the above error.

My case:

Directories and files of interest:

> D:\SF_ROOT_DIR\lib\autoload\sfClassLoader.class.php
>
> D:\SF_ROOT_DIR\lib\vendor\ClassLoader (contains:
>   https://github.com/symfony/ClassLoader/tree/2.6)
>
> D:\SF_ROOT_DIR\lib\vendor\cellbrush-1.0 (contains:
>   https://github.com/donquixote/cellbrush.)

Code:

SF_ROOT_DIR/config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../lib/autoload/sfClassLoader.class.php';

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader; 
use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcUniversalClassLoader;

sfCoreAutoload::register();

class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration
{
  public function setup()
  {
    $this->namespacesClassLoader();
    $this->enableAllPluginsExcept('sfPropelPlugin');
  }

   public function namespacesClassLoader() {
       if (extension_loaded('apc')) {
           $loader = new ApcUniversalClassLoader('S2A');
       } else {
           $loader = new UniversalClassLoader();
       }
       $loader->registerNamespaces(array(
          'Donquixote' => __DIR__ . '/../lib/vendor/cellbrush-1.0/src/Table'));
       $loader->register();
    }
}
```

actions.class.php

```
$table = \Donquixote\Cellbrush\Table\Table::create();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use composer and its autoloading.

Execute:

```
composer require donquixote/cellbrush
```

Now the library is installed in vendor directory and autoloader is generated, you just need to include it. Add this line to the top of `config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php`:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: Thank you @Marek, the alternative you proposed worked just fine. I had never used composer before so it took me a while to installed. Two things to add: first, the required really is: `require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/vendor/autoload.php';`, and second for thouse looking to use cellbrush library have in mind that sadly requieres PHP 4 or higher. Strictly, this isn't a precise solution for the problem i pose, but it does for the bigger one, so is a perfect alternative and i recommend it, hope somone else can help with the other alternative.